# how to move a rectangle shape on jpeg image in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, image, jpeg, shapes, drag

A task is assigned to me to mark a location using rectangle shape on a map image. The rectange shape should be adjustable by dragging using handler on the map image. I have drawn a shape on the image but I could not drag to mark the location on the jpeg image(map image).  After that, that updated Image with shape should be saved into local disk.
Please help me to drag the shape using handler on the map image(in jpeg format).

Answer (score 0):

I can tell  u how u can add the basic handler to draw and drag your shape.
I hope you must be using

```
using System.Drawing;
```

And the Code might be like:

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    rec = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);      
  }
}
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    rec.Width = e.X - rec.X;
    rec.Height = e.Y - rec.Y;
  }
}
```